# Problema com a seleção de abas

Tags: c#, html

Tenho 2 abas, uma que mostra minhas macros juntas e outra para mostrar as enviadas.
As macros juntas já vem selecionada por *default* e na `Page Load` tem o método que carrega os dados correspondentes da mesma

Quando clico na aba das macros enviadas, meu método nem é executado. Como faço para chamar um método dentro da li ?

O que pode ser?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Macros juntas</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#enviadas" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" runat="server" onserverclick="Carregamacrosenviadas">Macros enviadas</a></li>      
</ul>
```

Comment: O _plugin_ para as tabs pode estar a cancelar o método `onserverclick`. Qual o _plugin_ que estás a utilizar para as tabs? Qual o código presente na função `Carregamacrosenviadas` ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que só esteja faltando o atributo `data-toggle="tab"` na tab de macros enviadas:

```
<li><a runat="server" href ="#enviadas" data-toggle="tab" onserverclick="Carregamacrosenviadas">Macros enviadas</a></li>
```

Comment: quando coloco o atributo 'data-toggle="tab"' meu evento onserverclick não funciona, ele não chama meu método.

Comment: Você consegue rodar javascript nesta sua função? Se sim, basta forçar a exibição da tab correta, neste caso, `$('#myTab a[href="#enviadas"]').tab('show')`.

Comment: e se não? você saberia? ^.^

Comment: Tente através do atributo `onclick`:
`onclick="$(this).tab('show');"`

Comment: mesmo assim não estou conseguindo, que tenso !!!

Comment: Como faço para chamar um método que tenho na minha página dentro na <li> ? tentei onserverclick, onclick e nada !